# Can't hear WhatsApp voicenotes on my ear; only on loudspeaker

Tags: iphone, audio, whatsapp.app

Recently, out of nowhere, I lost the ability to listen to WhatsApp voice notes whenever I take the phone to my ear. When I do, I get the silent logo sign of iPhone, while in fact the phone is not silent. Also the volume is not low and is to maximum.

Whenever I take the phone away from my ear, the voice note plays normally on the loudspeaker.

Comment: Is this behaviour only affecting WhatsApp? Also, did the start of this behaviour coincide with anything else (e.g. after version 2.17.11 of WhatsApp was released on 28 March 2017, after updating to iOS 10.3, etc)?

Comment: This is only for whatsapp. other things work fine. I can hear normally via the ear section.

Answer (score 3):

Ok just open any voice message and take your phone close to ear, now press volume button to make the sound high. Actually you removed the voice totally when you was hearing the message before as some times it’s very loud and we trying sometimes to make the voice less for privacy for sourrondings.